# Nginx directing to wrong server name

Tags: nginx, nameserver

I am trying a bunch of things on my Node webapp hosted on DigitalOcean and this is how the NGINX's configuration file looks like.

```
server {
 server_name maindomain.xyz www.maindomain.xyz;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        #Another location here
}

server
{
        server_name *.maindomain.xyz; #server name for wildcard subdomains
        location /
        {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Now I had bought a new domain and as I did with the main one I have created an A record on DigitalOcean that lets newdomain.xyz to be directed to the webapp server.
But, weirdly enough if I try to browse the new domain on a browser, instead of getting a 502 error I get the main page of my web app which is linked from maindomain.xyz.

As you can see on NGINX I've never specified any directive for newdomain.xyz but for some reason it gets directed to the 5000 port where my node server runs which provides the built React web app through this block of code:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
{
    //Set static folder
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));

    app.get('*', (req,res) =>
    {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html')); //Path of the webapp's root
    });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server ${PORT}`));
```

Please be aware the I am steel a newbie and I couldn't find any solution to prevent this behaviour.
Thanks to you all.

EDIT for further clarification.
What is happening right now is this:
if I go to maindomain.xyz I get to the home page (that is the desired behaviour)

if I go to newdomain.xyz I STILL get to the home page even if I did not specify a server name for newdomain.xyz. That is the issue I want to resolve.

Comment: You didn't create a `server` block for your new domain name?!

Comment: No, that is exactly why I am super confused right now.

Comment: That's why it doesn't work!

Comment: Yeah I know, but why does it go to the home page even if I did not make a server name for the new domain? If I go to maindomain.xyz I expect to see the home page (which it does), but if I go to the new domain I expect to get an error page of some sorts, not the home page.

Comment: I've edited the question, to clarify things a bit.

Comment: nginx came with a default `server` block that served that purpose. Did you delete it or change it?

Comment: I've changed it, but I've commented everything that I am not using. This is a development server for the production one I'm using a brand new file.

Comment: OK, you should restore it to its original configuration. And only create new `server` blocks for your own domains.

Comment: You should consider making a `default_server` block in your nginx configuration, that handles all requests that do not match some active `server` block.

Comment: Thank you so much, you where right. But how come that NGINX falls back to the first server name if the ```server_name _;``` server is not present? For me it would be more logical the reasoning that if one specific domain is not specified it shouldn't be handled by NGIX, or it should return an error page.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html logical or not, but this is how nginx works

Comment: Fair enough I guess

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, basically I did delete the default server block

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

Apparently without it NGIX falls back to the first server when a non specified domain tries to connect.